# Java + Selenide. Не проходит элементарный тест

Tags: java, selenium

Впервые работаю с `Java` и `Intelij idea`, да и собственно с *Селенидом* тоже. Прежде использовал `с#` со студией и побывал *Селениум*. Сделал вроде все по инструкции (импровизация) с подключением библиотеки *селенида*, все компилирует без ошибок, а вот сам элементарный тест не работает, кто может помочь пожалуйста?

***Oшибка:***

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext

`Maven` и прочие не понятные "слова" не использовал, тупо создал новый проект, подключил внешнею библиотеку и написал код:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void firstTest(){
        open("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: если добавить еще какую-нибудь команду, например:  
`$(".lol").setValue("lolo");`  
то выбивает ошибку:
`Error:(10, 9) java: cannot access org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
  class file for org.openqa.selenium.WebElement not found`

Comment: библиотека не подключена

Comment: @SeniorPomidor если бы была не подключена - то не компилилось бы...

Comment: вот [решение](http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-common/2.0a5/org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor эти инструкции не подходят, так как не использую Maven SBT Gradle Ivy

Comment: Мало подробностей. Какую версию Selenide используете? Как прописали зависимости?

Comment: 4.4.1, просто кинул библиотеку в папку с проектом (как написано на сайте) и через properties подключил ее